# How do you use the Boolean modifier without horribly deforming the mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

[image: http://prntscr.com/9q8h1z]

I'm currently modeling a plane where the exterior was modeled first and the interior was added in with Ctrl + J as a separate object, so the plane as a whole is non manifold.

Here's the interior of the first class room:

[image]

This is in-between the interior and exterior (not connected):

[image: http://prntscr.com/9q8i21]

So, as you can imagine, I'm trying to cut a porthole into the plane with the porthole object. This is the boolean modifier on the plane (raising the modifier any higher deforms the plane):

[image]

Rather than getting a nice clean cut, I got this:

[image]

The interior part was cut through, but not the exterior. I find this extremely confusing, because it should have worked in theory. This is what the wireframe looked like before the modifier was applied:

[image]

In the image, the porthole object was selected, so in the plane mesh you could see 2 definite cuts. So how can I get it perfectly, just like the wireframe "preview"?

I thank you in advance for helping.

Comment: I avoid using the boolean mod for just this reason. bad mesh is always going to be there. try manually modelling the windows, it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: True story. Google for "blender how to make holes", you'll find better solutions. Boolean is completely useless in my opinion.

Comment: In situations like this, the problem is rarely the Boolean modifier, but rather the underlying geometry. If you want some kind of answer for your scenario it's more helpful to us to see the .blend you are using. [upload here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), you can always delete it later but -- at least we'll know if there's some solution.